# how do I display rating icons to the right of some text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0, joomla3.1, joomla3.2

I have a paranormal site where each investigation write up has a rating. In this situation my client wants to use skulls (not that it really matters). The site address is:

http://theripfiles.tv/j3upgrade/index.php/case-files/season-1

I need to display the phrase "PAL Rating:" with 1 to 5 skull icons to the right of it.

I attached the image I'm using to the site page above.

Image dimensions: 
width:102px
height 135px
5 rows of icons 27px in height
Top row has 5 icons. bottom row has 1 icon.

Here is what I have so far:

```
.pal-rating-static 
{
    background: url("../images/icons/pal-rating5.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 102px;
    height: 27px;
    display: block;
}

.pal-rating-5 { background-position: 0 0; }
.pal-rating-4 { background-position: -27px 0; }
.pal-rating-3 { background-position: -54px 0; }
.pal-rating-2 { background-position: -81px 0; }
.pal-rating-1 { background-position: -108px 0; }
```

I tried using similar CSS from this simple example but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

http://www.itsalif.info/content/displaying-star-rating-using-css-sprites

Comment: please add your html.  Also, I think you'll find you get more answers if you set up a http://jsfiddle.net example of what you've tried

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Do I just copy the page source into that address?

Comment: btw, there is no javascript involved in this.

Comment: doesn't matter, jsfiddle can just be html and CSS.  I'd go to your source file, copy the part you're trying to change into jsfiddle along with your CSS.  Try to recreate what it is you're hoping for and post the result

Comment: ps.. I fixed part of my issue after I posted and at my css code again. (smacking forehead). Changed the pal-rating5.png above to pal-rating-static.png and it shows up but now I can't get it to stay next to the phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site you have

```
.pal-rating-static {
background: url("../images/icons/pal-rating-static.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
width: 102px;
height: 27px;
display: block;
float: right;
}
```

Change that to

```
.pal-rating-static {
background: url("../images/icons/pal-rating-static.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
width: 102px;
height: 27px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yeah I messed up and forgot to change the icon name in my CSS before I posted the thread. Thank you very much though. I'm definitely closer to what I'm looking for. :)   I'm thinking I just need to work out my css for my phrase "PAL Rating:" and the left margin for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need to mess with background position for this one

```
.pal-rating-static {
    background: url("../images/icons/pal-rating5.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 102px;
    height: 27px;
    display: block;
}
```

if this is your bar with 5 'skulls' visible . then all that you need to do is make the container smaller when you want to display less 'skulls'

you can do this by adding an extra CSS class for numer of 'skulls'

so you will end up with something like this

```
.pal-rating-static.cat1 {
  width: 20px;
}

.pal-rating-static.cat2 {
  width: 40px;
}

.pal-rating-static.cat3 {
  width: 60px;
}

.pal-rating-static.cat4 {
  width: 80px;
}
```

hopefully this will solve your problem .. a fiddle would be very useful